# Removing position from HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm working on a something like music player. I'm building playlist on HashMap, I have a problem with deleting specific setlist(case 5). It works but when I delete position in the middle of the list case 1 (showing all playlists) no longer works because I have empty space (1,2,3,deleted,5,6....). Now how do I make those positions after deleted one decrease index by one? Looks like x-- doesn't solve my problem. I hope you understand my problem, here is the code, if you need me to translate anything to English just ask. Thanks for help!

```
package PLAYLIST2;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Odtwarzacz {

    // String lista;

    // Odtwarzacz(Playlist) {
    // lista = b;
    // }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nr;
        int koniec = 0;
        String nazwa11;
        int x = 0;
        HashMap<Integer, Playlist> Playlista = new HashMap<Integer, Playlist>();
        Playlista.put(x, new Playlist("Rock"));
        x++;
        Playlista.get(0).dodajUtwor("Stockholm Syndrome", "Muse", 2004);
        Playlista.get(0).dodajUtwor("Absolution", "Muse", 2004);
        Playlista.put(x, new Playlist("Pop"));
        x++;
        Scanner odczyt = new Scanner(System.in);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (koniec == 0) {
            System.out.println("_________________________");
            System.out.println("1.Wyświetl listę playlist");
            System.out.println("2.Dodaj playlistę");
            System.out.println("3.Wyświetl playlistę");
            System.out.println("4.Posortuj playlistę");
            System.out.println("5.Usuń playlistę");
            nr = odczyt.nextInt();
            switch (nr) {
            case 1: {
                System.out.println("Lista playlist: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                    System.out.println(i + ". " + Playlista.get(i).Nazwa());
                }
                break;
            }

            case 2: {
                System.out.print("Podaj nazwę nowej playlisty: ");
                nazwa11 = odczyt.next();
                Playlista.put(x, new Playlist(nazwa11));

                System.out.println("Dodano playlistę: "
                        + Playlista.get(x).Nazwa());
                x++;
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                System.out.print("Podaj numer playlisty:");
                nr = odczyt.nextInt();
                Playlista.get(nr).wyswietlListe();
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
                System.out.print("Podaj numer playlisty:");
                nr = odczyt.nextInt();
                Playlista.get(nr).sortuj();
                break;

            }
            case 5: {
                System.out.print("Podaj numer playlisty:");
                nr = odczyt.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Skasowano playlistę: "
                        + Playlista.get(nr).Nazwa());
                Playlista.remove(nr);
                x--;
                break;
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, why do you use Map instead of array?

Comment: A `Map` has no guarantee of any order in its entries (a `SortedMap` does however); what is more you cannot have a key and no value: at worst the value will be null.

Comment: It is a project for my university classes and i've been told to use hashmap.

Comment: actually is not a blank space, it's a hole in correlation of keys, but not a null entry...

Comment: If you are allowing the user to access the deleted items (which you are), what would you like to show them?  I think your code is already handling this OK.

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to need a HashMap.

A HashMap is just a key-value store that has no order.

In your case, a `List` seems like a better choice. It comes with an order since it is the main point of it.

You can specifically use a [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

```
List<Playlist> playlists = new ArrayList<>();
playlists.add(new Playlist("Rock"));
// ...
Playlist p = playlists.get(index);
```

Comment: You are totally right @Jean, but he said: *It is a project for my university classes and i've been told to use hashmap*

Comment: Exercise or not, as long as long the Map has an index for keys, then it should be an ArrayList.

Comment: I know you can, it is just totally useless

Comment: Calm down. You don't like my answer do not vote for it and move on.

Comment: i didn't voted yours, but if IOP asks for best option we will vote to close question as too broad. Also you are not answering OP's question, you are giving your opinion... btw: did you readed my first sentence? *You are totally right @Jean* this is my opinion, but SO is not for that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to safely remove and get correct keys after, you must iterate the `Map`

```
int count = 0;
boolean found = false;
Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer,String>> iter = TestMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry = iter.next();
    if("Sample".equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getValue())){
        iter.remove();   
        found = true;      
    }
    if (found) {
       // set the new key using count...
    }

    count ++;
}
```

Comment: Hey, what do you mean by set the new key? I'm also not sure I understand what does variable count do.

Answer (score 0):

first let me see if i understand your problem correctly or not . you like to reoder playlist after any delete operation. 1,2,3,4,5 . you delete 3 , then it should be 1,2,4,5 and not 1,2,  ,4,5.

if above is true , best is use linkedhashmap collection. also case1 you can rewrite as

```
case 1: {
                System.out.println("Lista playlist: ");
                for (Playlist pll:Playlista.values()) {
                    System.out.println(i + ". " + pll.Nazwa());
                }
                break;
            }
```